# How to use ember deployed jar

Tags: java, maven, ember.js, war, ember-cli

I have a spring mvc web project & an ember-cli project. I have used **ember deploy** to generate the maven jar. As required, all contents of the dist folder are copied into the jar.

I have supplied the dependency of this jar to my spring project and it is on the classpath. How can I ensure that all the contents of this jar are copied as a part of webResources?

I tried using maven-war-plugin but the webResources tag expects a directory to be specified. I am unaware of the syntax required to specify the jar as a directory of resource there.

P.S. : I am using Java 7, ember cli 1.13

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and errors I found the solution to problem. I am unsure if this is the right way of doing it, but had no other option as of now.

I changed the package type of 'ember-cli project' to `war` in maven-config.json (and obviously added `<type>war</type>` to the concerned dependency tag in spring project). This ensured that all the contents of ember war file were copied to the "webapps" folder of spring war file without making any other configuration.